# How to save plt image to local in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to save my plotted image to local, I've tried to follow some tutorials from the internet, but still can't, can anyone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

joined_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Kurs/clean_data/forecast.csv')

# First plot
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,8))
ax1.plot(joined_data["kurs_jual"])
ax1.set_xlabel("Tanggal", fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel("Kurs Jual")
ax1.set_title("Kurs Jual VND")

# second plot
ax2.plot(joined_data["kurs_beli"], color="orange")
ax2.set_xlabel("Tanggal", fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylabel("Kurs Beli")
ax2.set_title("Kurs Beli VND")
plt.show()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Kurs/clean_data/forecast_vnd.png')
```

Comment: Do you  mean saving to `~/.`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Kurs/clean_data/forecast_vnd.png')` before `plt.show()` else the saved picture would be blank.